# Scrolling UIViewController title

Tags: ios, scroll, titlebar, audio-player

Interface declaration:

```
@interface MusicPlayerViewController : UIViewController
```

I'm currently setting my title like this:

```
NSString* Title = [[[SongList objectAtIndex:currentIndex] childNamed:@"title"] value];
    Title = [Title stringByAppendingString:@" / "];
    Title = [Title stringByAppendingString:[[[SongList objectAtIndex:currentIndex] childNamed:@"artist"] value]];
    [self setTitle:Title];
```

Is it possible to make the title "Scroll" across the top of the menu? (smoothly, like it does in the music player?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to do so you'll need to make your own UILabel subclass then set it as the customView for the title. Or subclass UINavigationBar itself if you still want to be able to set the title normally.